# UI issue of Check boxes in FLUTTER DART

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I have of many checkboxes as You can see the image uploaded, please see the image first.

[image: PLEASE SEE THE IMAGE FIRST AND AFTER THAT YOU CAN UNDERSTAND MY PROBLEM]

Now the problem is that you can see the 3 cards views Conditions, Allergies and Past Surgeries. and all of these cards contains checkboxes and now what happens is that when I check or uncheck any box in Conditions Card so it works properly, but when I check or uncheck the box in allergies or Past Surgeries card the UI of the box does not change until I click on the Conditions Box.

What am I doing wrong and I will share the checkboxes codes also.

**CONDITIONS**

```
Checkbox(
              value: condition.selected,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _conditions[i].selected = value;
                });
              }),
```

**ALLERGIES**

```
Checkbox(
              value: allergy.selected,
              onChanged: (value) {
                _allergies[i].selected = value;

              }),
```

**PAST SURGERIES**

```
Checkbox(
              value: surgery.selected,
              onChanged: (value) {
                _surgeries[i].selected = value;
              
              }),
```

PLEASE HELP ME...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `setState` before your UI can update. The conditions card has `setState()` in it so you'll need to add `setState` to the 2 other cards also

**ALLERGIES**

```dart
Checkbox(
      value: allergy.selected,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _allergies[i].selected = value;
        });
      },
    );
```

**PAST SURGERIES**

```dart
Checkbox(
      value: surgery.selected,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() { \\ add setState
          _surgeries[i].selected = value;
        });
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have understood the problem why was the checkbox was not updating its ui